# tree command as a regex, but without the hidden files

Tags: regex, unix, command-line

Thanks to a nice post at http://murphymac.com/tree-command-for-mac/, I have my long lost linux command tree so I can see the complete directory tree with a single command.  I've implemented it via a function in my .bash_profile like this...

```
function tree {
find ${1:-.} -print | set -e "s;[^/]*/;   ;g"
}
```

...but what I would like is a version which does not include the hidden files, i.e. the ones that start with dot.

So I would like this output...

```
$tree Sites
   .DS_Store
   .localized
   images
      apache_pb.gif
      gradient.jpg
      macosxlogo.png
      web_share.gif
   index.html
```

... to become...

```
$tree Sites
   images
      apache_pb.gif
      gradient.jpg
      macosxlogo.png
      web_share.gif
   index.html
```

Comment: The question subject is badly written. Or, rather, it assumes a solution which is not by far the best one.

Comment: @Daniel Are you often a title Nazi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one little change:

```
find ${1:-.} ! -name '.*' -print | set -e "s;[^/]*/;   ;g"
```

The pattern `! -name '.*'` causes `find` not to match any filename (or directory name) that starts with a dot.

Comment: Nice.  I got stuck on the regex, when the solution was in the find.